# Tabs jquery very slow response time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use Tabs from jquery. See code below:

`<div class='tabs'>
<ul>
 <li><a href="funcName.php?id=1&tab=First">First</a></li>
 <li><a href="funcName.php?id=2&tab=Second">Second</a></li>
 <li><a href="funcName.php?id=3&tab=Third">Third</a></li>
</ul></div>`

Some times when i click on one tab the results from funcName.php are returned very slow (as you can see in the screenshot) but other times is very quick.

[image]

I don't know why is this happen because it is erratic. It is difficult to draw conclusions if it is because of the php side or the problem is in the ajax call.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

if an ajax call is made successfully there is nothing wrong with it, it is just your host that is responding late, or you are doing too much of data fetching or processing in your function.